# UITableViewCell with UITextfield not centeringY in correct manner

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want TableViewCells with a vertically centered `UITextField`. I think I do set the `NSLayoutConstraint` right, but the `textfield` is not centered. What did I do wrong?

[image]

```
func createCellAsEditableCell(){
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.width, self.contentView.frame.height))
    let views = ["textField" : textField]
    self.contentView.addSubview(textField)

    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[textField]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: textField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    textField.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    self.contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([verticalConstraint])
    textField.placeholder = "Textfield"
}
```

Comment: have you implemented `heightForRowAtIndexPath` for tableview? It looks like the cells are not of optimal height.

Comment: Yes it is implemented. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see here is that you are mixing setting frame from code and setting constraints at the same time. You do not want to have auto resizing mask translated into constraints, then you position the textField in the container but making it too big to fit the contentView rectangle according to the positioning constraints (look at the width of the textfield and the margin you set for it).

What I would do is:

1) create textfield without setting its frame from code (use different initialiser -> in objective-C that would be [[UITextField alloc]init])

2) leave the centre constraints as they are

3) set vertical constraint like this `V:|[textField]|`

4) set the horizontal one like this `H:|-20-[textField]|`

5) do not turn off translationAutoresizingMask on the contentView, **you are not responsible for layouting it in its container** so it is clearly wrong!

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.
Can you tell me a bit more, what the translateAutoResizingMask actually does ?

Comment: Please consider upvoting if that helped you. translateAutoResizingMask (translates autoresizing masks to constraints)[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints] you shoudn't set it to NO for the components you are not layouting - basically saying - which you are not adding to the view hierarchy :)

Comment: [right link to the description of the autoresizingMaskFlag](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)